# How can I determine the mean size (area) of the surface reconstruction domains from a LEED (low energy electron diffraction) pattern?

Tags: electrons, solid-state-physics, diffraction

How can I determine the mean size (area) of the surface reconstruction domains from a low-energy electron diffraction (LEED) pattern?

The cross-section of the electron beam is definitely going to be much larger than the average domain area, so I can't just measure every single domain. There will probably have be to some statistical approach right? And I think spot intensity profile might have to be used too.

Comment: What about the LEED pattern changes with the size of a domain?

Comment: You mean something like two difracting patterns from two domains mixing up if beam cross-section is too big?

Answer (score 1):

Focus your beam to a spot size smaller than the domain size and scan the intensity of a peak that is due to the surface reconstruction.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Why is the intensity of the peak relevant?

Comment: @Andrej The peaks due to the reconstruction on the orientation of the surface domain. Depending on the symmetry, I think there will be only two or three possible orientations, so such peaks will be "on" or "off".

Comment: What if I have reasonable expectation that beam's cross-section has to be much larger than the domain size?

Comment: @Andrej Use an STM (scanning tunneling microscope)?